# PHP Get all possible percentage options into array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

What I am trying to do is get all possible percentage value combinations for a given set of keys in an array. Here is what I have so far, which is supposed to do all possible combinations up to 5:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class CalculateController extends Controller
{

    protected $percentages = [];

    protected $maxPercent = 5;

    public function index()
    {
        $keys = ['key1' => 0, 'key2' => 0, 'key4' => 0, 'key4' => 0];
        $percentKeys = [];

        $arrayKeys = array_keys($keys);

        foreach($keys as $key => $value) {

            $keyPlacement = array_search($key, array_keys($keys));

                while($keyPlacement >= 0){
                    $keys[$arrayKeys[$keyPlacement]] = 0;
                    $keys = $this->loop($keys, $arrayKeys[$keyPlacement]);
                $keyPlacement = $keyPlacement - 1;
                }
        }

        $this->percentages = array_unique($this->percentages, SORT_REGULAR);
        print_r($this->percentages);

    }

    public function loop( $array, $key ){
        for($i = 0 ; $i < $this->maxPercent + 1 ; $i++) {
            $array[$key] = $i;
            $this->percentages[] = $array;
        }
        return $array;
    }

}
```

This is outputting:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 0
        [key2] => 0
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 1
        [key2] => 0
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 2
        [key2] => 0
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 3
        [key2] => 0
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 4
        [key2] => 0
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 0
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 1
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 2
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 3
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 4
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 0
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 1
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 2
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 3
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 4
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 0
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 1
        [key4] => 0
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 2
        [key4] => 0
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 3
        [key4] => 0
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 4
        [key4] => 0
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 0
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 1
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 2
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 3
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 4
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 0
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 1
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 2
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 3
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 4
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 0
    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 1
    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 2
    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 3
    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 4
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[42] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 0
        [key4] => 5
    )

[43] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 1
        [key4] => 5
    )

[44] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 2
        [key4] => 5
    )

[45] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 3
        [key4] => 5
    )

[46] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 4
        [key4] => 5
    )

[48] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 0
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[49] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 1
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[50] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 2
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[51] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 3
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[52] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 5
        [key2] => 4
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[54] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 0
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[55] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 1
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[56] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 2
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[57] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 3
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

[58] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 4
        [key2] => 5
        [key3] => 5
        [key4] => 5
    )

)
```

So I'm close but not quite there. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me from your description what you're trying to achieve. You've shown what you're getting, but you haven't shown what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you have a max percentage (in your case 5) and a certain number of keys (in this case 1...4). You want to populate these four keys with *all possible values* of all integer percentages, zero included, up to the max included, with repetitions allowed.

So in this case from 0 0 0 0 up to 5 5 5 5.

In this case, you can have at the most `pow($MaxPercentage+1, $keyNumber)` values in your result. Given any number from 0 to this maximum number, its combination will be

```
function nthCombo($idx, $keyNumber, $top) {
    $result = array_fill(0, $keyNumber, 0);
    $pos = 0;
    while ($idx) {
        $result[$pos++] = $idx % $top;
        $idx = floor($idx / $top);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

So if you want all the percentages, all together:

```
$maxPercentage = 5;
$keyNumber = 4;
$top = $maxPercentage + 1;

$combinations = pow($top, $keyNumber);

print $combinations . "\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $combinations; $i++) {
    $allcombi[] = nthCombo($i, $keyNumber, $top);
}
```

This also allows you to work without the need of actually *storing* the result, you can process it one value at a time.

(The mapping to named keys is immediate using `array_combine()`)

## specific percentages or strings

If you have a given number of percentages but they aren't in any simple progression (for example 11%, 13%, 22%, 22.5%, 27%, 31%), or maybe they are *strings* like [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ], you can still use the approach above. You just use a *map*:

```
$percs = [ 11%, 13%, 22%, 22.5%, 27%, 31% ];
```

Now when the algorithm gives you $combo = [ 0, 2, 1, 5 ] you translate every number, e.g. 2, into $percs[2], which is 22%:

```
$perc2 = array_map(
    function($idx) use ($percs) { 
        return $percs[$idx]; 
    }, 
    $combo
);
```

and obtain $perc2 = [ 11%, 22%, 13%, 31% ].